# What Object has Active Focus in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, focus, qtquickcontrols2

I have a complex GUI with `QML` but in some situations, I lose my **focus** and don't know what object has active focus.

Are there any tools or ways to search in `QML` files and find focused object?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I use this line to see which item has active focus:

```
Window {
    onActiveFocusItemChanged: print("activeFocusItem", activeFocusItem)
}
```

This code responds to changes in the [`activeFocusItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#activeFocusItem-prop) property of `Window` by printing out the item with active focus. `ApplicationWindow` from Qt Quick Controls [1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html) and [2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html) have the same property since they derive from `Window`.

---

To find out *how* an item got focus, you can set the `QT_LOGGING_RULES` environment variable to `qt.quick.focus = true`. This enables logging for Qt's internal focus handling. The output can be a bit tricky to follow though..

Since you're using Qt Quick Controls 2, it's worth noting that each control has a [`focusPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#focusPolicy-prop) property which determines how the control gets focus. The default for controls like `Button` is `Qt.StrongFocus`, which means that buttons get focus after being clicked or tabbed into. If you're seeing that a control has focus and you don't want it to, just set its `focusPolicy` to `Qt.NoFocus`:

```
focusPolicy: Qt.NoFocus
```

Comment: i found my active focused object! now is there any solution to find where focus is changing?

Comment: Are you using Qt Quick Controls 2?

Comment: Yes i use qtquick controls 2

Comment: This is useful, but it doesn't answer how to have a single line of code find the active window. Instead, it requires the line of code to be propagated throughout all the components. This is a problem if, for instance, you'd like to close a window as a result of a global action. Any thoughts on how to grab an active window from anywhere?

Comment: @KennSebesta https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#focusWindow is probably the easiest way. I don't think there's a QML API for it.